# React Route for NAVLINK Received TRUE for a non-boolean attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using Navlink

```js
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
const MainMenu = () => {
    return (
        <nav className="main-menu d-none d-lg-block">
            <ul className="d-flex">
                <li>
                    <NavLink exact to="/">
                        Home
                    </NavLink>
                </li>
            </ul>
</nav>)};
```

I am getting a warning in my console saying

```
bundle.js:30762 Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `exact`.
If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: exact="true" or exact={value.toString()}.
at a
at LinkWithRef (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:59806:5)
at NavLinkWithRef (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:59852:21)
at li
at div
at header
at Header (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:11996:91)
at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:60295:5)
at NavScrollTop (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:3960:51)
at Wrapper (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:4034:78)
at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:60228:15)
at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:59704:5)
at App
```

Any idea how can I fix it? I tried other stack overflow details but could not come up with anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `react-router-dom@6` the `NavLink` component has no `exact` prop, so it's being passed down to the DOM it seems.

[NavLink](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#navlink)

> ```
> declare function NavLink(
>   props: NavLinkProps
> ): React.ReactElement;
>
> interface NavLinkProps
>   extends Omit<
>     LinkProps,
>     "className" | "style" | "children"
>   > {
>   caseSensitive?: boolean;
>   children?:
>     | React.ReactNode
>     | ((props: { isActive: boolean }) => React.ReactNode);
>   className?:
>     | string
>     | ((props: {
>         isActive: boolean;
>       }) => string | undefined);
>   end?: boolean;
>   style?:
>     | React.CSSProperties
>     | ((props: {
>         isActive: boolean;
>       }) => React.CSSProperties);
> }
> ```

## Solution

The solution is to remove the `exact` prop from your code since it's not doing anything for you.

```
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const MainMenu = () => {
  return (
    <nav className="main-menu d-none d-lg-block">
      <ul className="d-flex">
        <li>
          <NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};
```

### Updated Solution Code

Since it seems you are rendering a link for the home page and you don't want it to also match for sub routes, use the `end` prop.

> If the `end` prop is used, it will ensure this component isn't matched
> as "active" when its descendant paths are matched. For example, to
> render a link that is only active at the website root and not any
> other URLs, you can use:
>
> ```
> <NavLink to="/" end>
>   Home
> </NavLink>
> ```

```
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const MainMenu = () => {
  return (
    <nav className="main-menu d-none d-lg-block">
      <ul className="d-flex">
        <li>
          <NavLink end to="/">Home</NavLink>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};
```